# How to write a function that can calculate power in Java. No loops

Tags: java, repeat, exponent

I've been trying to write a simple function in Java that can calculate a number to the nth power without using loops.
I then found the *Math.pow(a, b)* class... or method still can't distinguish the two am not so good with theory. So i wrote this..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 2;

    int b = 31;

    System.out.println(Math.pow(a, b));

    }
```

Then i wanted to make my own *Math.pow* without using loops i wanted it to look more simple than loops, like using some type of *Repeat* I made a lot of research till i came across the *commons-lang3* package i tried using *StringUtils.repeat*
So far I think this is the Syntax:-

```
public static String repeat(String str, int repeat)
    StringUtils.repeat("ab", 2);
```

The **problem** i've been facing the **past 24hrs** or more is that *StringUtils.repeat(String str, int 2);* repeats strings not out puts or numbers or calculations.
Is there anything i can do to overcome this or is there any other better approach to creating a function that calculates powers?
**without using loops or Math.pow**

This might be funny but it took me while to figure out that *StringUtils.repeat* only repeats strings this is how i tried to overcome it. incase it helps

```
 public static int repeat(int cal, int repeat){
     cal = 2+2;
     int result = StringUtils.repeat(cal,2);
     return result;
}
```

can i not use recursion maybe some thing like this

```
public static RepeatThis(String a)
{
     System.out.println(a);
     RepeatThis(a);
}
```

*just trying to understand java in dept thanks for all your comments even if there were syntax errors as long as the logic was understood that was good for me* :)

Comment: The fact that it's called `String`Utils should give you a hint that it's for working with `String`s and not numbers...

Comment: If you are trying to re-implement Math.pow() for learning purposes then fine but otherwise just stick to this default implementation. You will not be able to write a better one yourself. Using non-standard implementations only add unnecessary complexity to your code and makes it harder for other people to understand it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yea you're right.

Comment: @Muton yes it's obviously for learning purpose. I don't think there is any point to re-implementing something like Math.pow() atleast not with my level of skills. but still thanks for the advice, its always good to be reminded of such things :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with recursion:

```
int pow(int base, int power){
    if(power == 0) return 1;
    return base * pow(base, --power);
}
```

Comment: can i not use recursion maybe something like this  
public static RepeatThis(String a)
{
     System.out.println(a);
     RepeatThis(a);
}

Comment: You can do it also by simulating stack. You should also remember that every iteration can be converted to recursion, but not every recursion can be converted to iteration. Recursive function are getting more and more important with a rise of functional programming, so give it a try.

Comment: @Craiz if you want to carry out an operation a parameterised number of times you have to either loop or recurse. There is no other way of doing it. What do you think `StringUtils.repeat` does?

Comment: @user thanks a lot am already looking into recursion but its really annoying when you cant get a code done the way you imagined it to be the first time hahaha

Comment: @Boris the Spider yes i think i get that now. if you check my question you'll find that i edited it I just added something at the end. I guess was just trying to force that logic into java. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

Another implementation with O(Log(n)) complexity

```
public static long pow(long base, long exp){        
    if(exp ==0){
        return 1;
    }
    if(exp ==1){
        return base;
    }

    if(exp % 2 == 0){
        long half = pow(base, exp/2);
        return half * half;
    }else{
        long half = pow(base, (exp -1)/2);
        return base * half * half;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Function to handle +/- exponents with O(log(n)) complexity.

```
double power(double x, int n){
 if(n==0)
  return 1;

  if(n<0){
      x = 1.0/x;
      n = -n;
  }
 double ret = power(x,n/2);
 ret = ret * ret;
 if(n%2!=0)
   ret = ret * x;
 return ret;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This one handles negative exponential:

```
public static double pow(double base, int e) {
    int inc;
    if(e <= 0) {
        base = 1.0 / base;
        inc = 1;
    }
    else {
        inc = -1;
    }
    return doPow(base, e, inc);
}

private static double doPow(double base, int e, int inc) {
    if(e == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return base * doPow(base, e + inc, inc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in Production recursion just does not provide high end performance.

```
double power(double num, int exponent)
{

double value=1;
int Originalexpn=exponent;
double OriginalNumber=num;

if(exponent==0)
    return value;

if(exponent<0)
{
    num=1/num;
    exponent=abs(exponent);
}

while(exponent>0)
{
    value*=num;
    --exponent;
}

cout << OriginalNumber << " Raised to  " << Originalexpn << " is " << value << endl;
return value;
```

}

Comment: This is with the loop, however. A while loop but it is also easy to build a for-style loop if while is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, create your own recursive function:

```
public static int repeat(int base, int exp) {
 if (exp == 1) {
  return base;
 }

 return base * repeat(base, exp - 1);
}
```

> Math.pow(a, b)

`Math` is the class, `pow` is the method, `a` and `b` are the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
public int mypow(int a, int e){
    if(e == 1) return a;
    return a * mypow(a,e-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a O(log(n)) code that calculates the power of a number. Algorithmic technique used is divide and conquer. It also accepts negative powers i.e., x^(-y)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PowerOfANumber{
        public static void main(String args[]){
                float result=0, base;
                int power;
                PowerOfANumber calcPower = new PowerOfANumber();
                /* Get the user input for the base and power */
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the base");   
                base=input.nextFloat();
                System.out.println("Enter the power");
                power=input.nextInt();
                result = calcPower.calculatePower(base,power);
                System.out.println(base + "^" + power + " is " +result);
        }   
        private float calculatePower(float x, int y){ 
                float temporary;
                /* Termination condition for recursion */    
                if(y==0)
                        return 1;
                temporary=calculatePower(x,y/2);
                /* Check if the power is even */
                if(y%2==0)
                        return (temporary * temporary);
                else{
                        if(y>0)
                                return (x * temporary * temporary);
                        else
                                return (temporary*temporary)/x;
                }    
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remembering the [definition of the logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Examples), this can be done with *ln* and *exp* if these functions are allowed. Works for any positive base and any real exponent (not necessarily integer):

```
x = 6.7^4.4
ln(x) = 4.4 * ln(6.7) = about 8.36
x = exp(8.36) = about 4312.5
```

You can read more [here](https://brownmath.com/alge/loglaws.htm) and also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332058/how-can-i-write-exponential-function-with-base-other-than-e). Java provides both [ln](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-) and [exp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#exp-double-).

Answer (score -1):

A recursive method would be the easiest for this :

```
int power(int base, int exp) {
    if (exp != 1) {
        return (base * power(base, exp - 1));
    } else {
        return base;
    }
}
```

where `base` is the number and `exp` is the exponenet

Comment: Thanks, forgot the else.

Comment: You don't need an `else` as there is a `return`. There are no brackets which is generally bad practice and the code is unreadable.

Comment: I added the brackets. and `else` is mandatory for this function btw otherwise it wont compile as if the condition fails, it will the function will just return whearas it should return a int

Comment: Nope, look at the other examples. You need an `if` but you can just `return` without an `else`. P.S. I formatted your code, I really don't understand what's so difficult about that.

Comment: Other examples work because there are other return statements besides the one in the `if` block. So `int` will be returned even if `if` fails. Ofcourse I can just `return base` without the `else` but isn't that the same thing here?