# how to get exponents without using the math.pow for java

Tags: java, math, pow, exponent

This is my program

```
// ************************************************************
    // PowersOf2.java
    //
    // Print out as many powers of 2 as the user requests
    //
    // ************************************************************

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PowersOf2 {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        int numPowersOf2; //How many powers of 2 to compute
        int nextPowerOf2 = 1; //Current power of 2
        int exponent= 1;
        double x;

         //Exponent for current power of 2 -- this
        //also serves as a counter for the loop Scanner

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many powers of 2 would you like printed?");
        numPowersOf2 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("There will be " + numPowersOf2 + " powers of 2 printed");
        //initialize exponent -- the first thing printed is 2 to the what?

    while( exponent <= numPowersOf2)
        {
        double x1 = Math.pow(2, exponent);
        System.out.println("2^" + exponent + " = " + x1);
                exponent++;
        }   
//print out current power of 2
//find next power of 2 -- how do you get this from the last one?
//increment exponent

    }
}
```

The thing is that I am not allowed to use the math.pow method, I need to find another way to get the correct answer in the while loop.

Comment: Multiply maybe ?!? After all `next power = previous power * 2`..eg `2^1=2` `2^2 = 4`, `2^3 = 4*2 = 8`

Comment: Make sure to preserve whether the power is negative. If so, divide, not multiply.

Comment: to get exponents you use `log`, not `pow`. `pow` is used to get the powers

Answer (score 15):

Powers of 2 can simply be computed by [Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

```
int exponent = ...
int powerOf2 = 1 << exponent;
```

Even for the more general form, you should **not** compute an exponent by "multiplying `n` times". Instead, you could do [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Answer (score 1):

If there are no performance constraints you can do:

```
double x1=1;

for(int i=1;i<=numPowersOf2;i++){
   x1 =* 2
}
```

Comment: There are performance constraints on this one. Will be `O(n)`. It can be done in `O(1)` time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post that allows both negative/positive power calculations.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23003962/3538289

Function to handle +/- exponents with O(log(n)) complexity.

```
double power(double x, int n){
 if(n==0)
  return 1;

  if(n<0){
      x = 1.0/x;
      n = -n;
  }
 double ret = power(x,n/2);
 ret = ret * ret;
 if(n%2!=0)
   ret = ret * x;
 return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own `power` function.

The complexity of the `power` function depends on your requirements and constraints. 
For example, you may constraint exponents to be only positive integer.

Here's an example of `power` function:

```
public static double power(double base, int exponent) {
    double ans = 1;
    if (exponent != 0) {
        int absExponent = exponent > 0 ? exponent : (-1) * exponent;
        for (int i = 1; i <= absExponent; i++) {
            ans *= base;
        }

        if (exponent < 0) {
            // For negative exponent, must invert
            ans = 1.0 / ans;
        }
    } else {
        // exponent is 0
        ans = 1;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this based on this [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring):

```
 public double myPow(double x, int n) {

    if(n < 0) {
        if(n == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            n = (n+1)*(-1);
            return 1.0/(myPow(x*x, n));
        }
        n = n*(-1);
        return (double)1.0/myPow(x, n);
    }
    double y = 1;
    while(n > 0) {
        if(n%2 == 0) {
           x = x*x; 
        }
        else {
            y = y*x;
            x = x*x;
        }
         n = n/2;
    }
    return y;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether your comment about using a loop is a desire or a requirement.  If it's just a desire there is a math identity you can use that doesn't rely on `Math.Pow`.

```
xy = ey∙ln(x)
```

In Java this would look like

```
public static double myPow(double x, double y){
  return Math.exp(y*Math.log(x));
}
```

If you really need a loop, you can use something like the following

```
public static double myPow(double b, int e) {
  if (e < 0) {
    b = 1 / b;
    e = -e;
  }

  double pow = 1.0;
  double intermediate = b;
  boolean fin = false;

  while (e != 0) {
    if (e % 2 == 0) {
      intermediate *= intermediate;
      fin = true;
    } else {
      pow *= intermediate;
      intermediate = b;
      fin = false;
    }
    e >>= 1;
  }

  return pow * (fin ? intermediate : 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set the variables

int numPowersOf2;        //How many powers of 2 to compute
int nextPowerOf2 = 1;    //Current power of  2
int exponent = 0;  


/* User input here */

// Loop and print results

do
   {

    System.out.println ("2^" + exponent + " = " + nextPowerOf2);

    nextPowerOf2 = nextPowerOf2*2;

    exponent ++;
  } 
while (exponent < numPowersOf2);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how I managed without using "myPow(x,n)", but by making use of "while". (I've only been learning Java for 2 weeks so excuse, if the code is a bit lumpy :)

```
    String base ="";
    String exp ="";
    BufferedReader value = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {System.out.print("enter the base number: ");
        base = value.readLine();
        System.out.print("enter the exponent: ");
        exp = value.readLine(); }
    catch(IOException e){System.out.print("error");}

    int x = Integer.valueOf(base);
    int n = Integer.valueOf(exp);
    int y=x;
    int m=1;       
    while(m<n+1) {
        System.out.println(x+"^"+m+"= "+y);
        y=y*x;
        m++;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement pow function without using built-in Math.pow(), we can use the below recursive way to implement it. To optimize the runtime, we can store the result of power(a, b/2) and reuse it depending on the number of times is even or odd.

```
static float power(float a, int b)
{
    float temp;
    if( b == 0)
        return 1;
    temp = power(a, b/2); 

    // if even times
    if (b%2 == 0)
        return temp*temp;
    else  // if odd times
    {
        if(b > 0)
            return a * temp * temp;
        else  // if negetive i.e. 3 ^ (-2)
            return (temp * temp) / a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is very late, but there's a very simple solution you can use if you are allowed to have variables that store the base and the exponent.

```
public class trythis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b = 2;
        int p = 5;
        int r = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++) {
            r *= b;
        }
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

This will work with positive and negative bases, but not with negative powers.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exponential value without using `Math.pow()` you can use a loop:
As long as the count is less than b (your power), your loop will have an 
additional "* a" to it. Mathematically, it is the same as having a `Math.pow()`

```
while (count <=b){
    a= a* a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

```
public static int exponent(int base, int power) {
   int answer = 1;

   for(int i = 0; i < power; i++) {
      answer *= base;
   }

   return answer;
}
```